# Problum with the && operators in if condition in PHP?

Tags: php

i am facing problem in my if condition if PHP code.i am using the && operator to validate both the conditions for image height and width  but it only checks the first condition.

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize('abc.jpg');

     if($width < 400 && $height < 200){
```

//do some thing
        }

```
 but it only validate the image width.
```

any hint??

Comment: What is the output of width and height when you print them?

Comment: What do you mean - "it only validate the image width"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&&` operator is a lazy bastard. If the leftmost operation returns `false`, it does not feel the need to check any further. So, I'd say your image is 400 (or more) pixels in width, which means the height naturally will never be checked.

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this:

```
if ($info = getimagesize("abc.jpg")) {
    if ($info[0] < 400 && $info[1] < 200) {
        // your code continues here...
    }
}
```

You can also write it in a more functional fashion (indexes go out):

```
if ($info = getimagesize("abc.jpg")) {
    if (current($info) < 400 && next($info) < 200) {
        // your code continues here...
    }
}
```

In any case, the `getimagesize()` function returns an array with more than two components, so that won't work.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: it is giving the same output no results are changed

Comment: You must have something wrong in your php.ini or maybe the server you're testing your code against doesn't have some required modules/dependencies. Check this snippet I've created for you. It works for me on both testing and production servers (I just checked it just in case). http://pastebin.com/KtGMUkSq